# What value will recv() return if it receives a valid TCP packet with payload sized 0

Tags: tcp, recv

In TCP socket programming, if `recv()` returns 0, it is taken as an indication that the other side closed its connection. However, AFAIK, the TCP RFC does not mandate the payload of TCP to be > 0. So, theoretically, a TCP stack can receive a message with payload 0.

So, essentially my question is what will `recv()` returns if it receives a packet of payload sized 0? If it returns 0, then how do we distinguish it from a closed connection indication.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

TCP segments with a payload size of 0 are ubiquitous - they occur in pretty much every real-world TCP stream.  They're sent whenever one side wishes to acknowledge reciept of data from the other, but has no data to send of its own.  (These are commonly known as "ACK packets", but an "ACK packet" is just a regular segment that happens to contain no data).

Since such packets do not contain any data to deliver to the user application, they will not cause `recv()` to return - `recv()` will continue blocking until some actual data arrives.  If `recv()` returns 0, then it is a definite indication that the other end has closed its side of the connection and won't be sending any more data.

Remember that TCP is stream-oriented: there is **not** a 1-to-1 mapping between the data returned by a single `recv()` call and the data in a single TCP segment.  A single `recv()` call might return a block of data that overlaps several TCP segments, and the data in a single TCP segment might be returned in multiple `recv()` calls.  The boundaries between TCP segments are not visible to the application using the BSD sockets API.  If you want such boundaries, you need to either implement yourself using an application-layer protocol within the TCP stream, or use a datagram-oriented protocol like UDP.

Comment: ACK packets will have an ACK flag set.

Comment: @AlastairG: Right, but every packet other than the initial `SYN` or a connection reset has the `ACK` bit set.

Comment: Yes, true, I'd forgotten that :) I'm not sure they necessarily have to, it's just good practice.

Answer (score 3):

Right, according to POSIX if `recv` returns `0`, then the connection is shut down correctly by the peer.

If someone has managed to send a TCP packet with a zero-sized payload, then the OS **doesn't have to return any data** to the process being blocked on `recv` system call on that socket.

Remember that TCP payloads form a continuous stream that may be randomly sliced by the OS, not a sequence of datagrams that must be returned during a single system call.